# Is it possible to run fsck to only see errors on mounted disk

Tags: disk, fsck

We have RedHat 7.2 OS.

```
/dev/sdc is mounted to /bla/appLO
```

Is it possible to run `fsck` on mounted disks (without `umount /bla/appLO`)
and to see only the errors if they exist?

Example:

```
e2fsck -n /dev/sdc
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Warning!  /dev/sdc is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
/dev/sdc: clean, 11/1310720 files, 126322/5242880 blocks
```

Does `fsck -n` show the error even though the disk is mounted?

Comment: You can use exit code of command `fsck`. But you can get errors in fs because is mounted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No.**

**You should never run `fsck` on a mounted filesystem.** Correcting errors on a live filesystem will mess up your disk. Even if you run the tool in read-only mode (without error correction) **the results can't be trusted**. This is true even if the filesystem is mounted read-only.

From `man e2fsck`:

> Note that  in  general  it  is  not  safe  to  run  `e2fsck`  on  mounted
>          filesystems.   The only exception is if the `-n` option is specified, and
>          `-c`, `-l`, or `-L` options are not specified.   However, even if it is  safe
>          to do so, the results printed by `e2fsck` are not valid if the filesystem
>          is mounted.   If  `e2fsck`  asks  whether  or  not  you  should  check  a
>          filesystem  which  is mounted, the only correct answer is ``no''.  Only
>          experts who really know what they are doing should  consider  answering
>          this question in any other way.

From `man fsck`:

> For some filesystem-specific checkers, the `-n` option will cause the fs-specific fsck to avoid attempting to repair any problems, but simply report such problems to stdout. This is however not true for all filesystem-specific checkers. In particular, `fsck.reiserfs(8)` will not report any corruption if given this option. `fsck.minix(8)` does not support the `-n` option at all.

You should take the time to unmount the disk and do a proper filesystem check; results that cannot be trusted aren't useful at all.

Comment: thank you , could you help me with my question on - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439661/mount-verify-disk-status-disk-isnt-read-write

Comment: I already seen your question, it puzzles me. I've never seen `ew` in the output of `mount`. I'd be interested to know the answer too.

Comment: Does this prohibition against fsck, even with `-n` specified, include on filesystems that are mounted read-only?

Comment: @DanielGriscom I'd say yes, as fsck would need to do writes on the filesystem anyway, in case of errors.

Comment: @dr01 No: with the `-n` option fsck makes no changes to the filesystem, correct? So, if the filesystem is mounted read-only then the mounted state won't confuse fsck, and if `fsck -n` is used then no fsck changes would be made and the filesystem couldn't be corrupted, right?

Comment: I've added the `fsck` man page output to the answer. By doing this you might get incorrect results (as I wrote in my answer, 2nd paragraph), and errors won't be fixed anyway. Perhaps it's just me, but I like to play safe, and would never run `fsck` on any mounted fs.